# A palette display in IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2.3

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, palette

Am using jsp to develop my project in IntelliJ Ultimate version 2016.2.3 , but how can I be able to use the palette, to allow drag and drop. Like that of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA does not include a visual designer for JSP pages.